# Bevel (from Blender Guru Tutorial: Architectural Interior)

Tags: bevel

There is a problem:
https://youtu.be/p5q_P8WQegQ?t=29m5s he is adding a bevel and nothing change in my project. Any ideas why?

screen:

[image]
updated:

I tried to scale Remove Doubles and i tried corret object scale. And i still have the problem. If i uncheck Clamp Overlap then I got weird things. https://preview.ibb.co/kTWoMJ/2018_05_15_2.png

[image]

Comment: Without seeing your scene or setup we can't do much for you.

Comment: screen attached! this is not a reason to give - dude.

Comment: Not a reason to give what? "doing nothing" is not descriptive for people who want to help. Can you upload the file?

Comment: A very common issue is incorrect object scale. Try Ctrl+A/Scale

Answer (score 0):

like *Raipav1* Stated, we cannot do anything if we do not have any information on the model. What I can suggest you is to uncheck **Clamp Overlap** in the settings, if the bevel now works, there is a problem on your mesh. There can be a lot of problems, but one of the most common in this case are duplicates. To Solve this, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode, press <kbd>W</kbd> and then **Remove Doubles**.

Comment: Hello I tried to scale Remove Doubles and i tried corret object scale. And i still have the problem. If i uncheck Clamp Overlap then I got weird things. https://preview.ibb.co/kTWoMJ/2018_05_15_2.png